# ajax posted object not receiving at the controller

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc, http-post

I have the following jquery $.post code.

```
var cbvalues = {};
cbvalues.A= $('#checkbox1').is(':checked');
cbvalues.B= $('#checkbox2').is(':checked');

var senddata = some string;
$.post('@Url.Content('+url')',{searchitems: cbvalues,   key:senddata },function(data){ 
    //some code 
});
```

The model class CheckBox

```
 public class CheckBox
 {
     public Boolean A {get; set;}
     public Boolean B {get; set;}
 }
```

The controller code is as follows

```
 public ActionResult PostAction(CheckBox searchitems, string key)
 {
    // searchitems.A is always false
    // searchitems.B is always false

 }
```

I can get the value of key here. But i cannot get the value for the **searchitems** object.
The post is working corretly. I can see the values being posted correctly in the Firebug Console. 
I Think the problem should be with the controller or should i be using $.ajax() instead of $.post().

Please help me solve the issue.

Firebug posted Values.

key:    test
searchitems[A]: true
searchitems[B]: true

Comment: What you mean "url"???

Comment: Can you post what values are being sent to the controller from firebug?

Comment: @Shanky..Are you using html controls or html helpers in your view?

Comment: no.. the checkbox is plain html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change it to:

```
var cbvalues = {};
    cbvalues.A= $('#checkbox1').is(':checked');
    cbvalues.B= $('#checkbox2').is(':checked');
```

Comment: That was a a typo. It is written corrctly in my original code

Answer (score 0):

`@Url.Content` doesn't need '' as it is c# Razor code. And the CBValues do not match the checkbox type.

Use:

```
var cbvalues = {};
cbvalues.A = $('#checkbox1').is(':checked');
cbvalues.B = $('#checkbox2').is(':checked');
```

Comment: That was a a typo. It is written corrctly in my original code